# Getting "<Property Name> was already registered by "<Control Name>" error in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a user control in WPF that has a binding to a Dependency Property. When I try to compile the app, I get a "Property Name" was already registered by "ControlName" error, and the designer shows a "Cannot create an instance of "User Control" error.

Here is what my simple control looks like:

**ExampleUserControl.xaml:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ExampleApp1.ExampleUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >

    <TextBox Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ExampleUserControl}}, Path=SomeStringValue}" />

</UserControl>
```

**ExampleUserControl.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class ExampleUserControl : UserControl
{

    public DependencyProperty SomeStringValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SomeStringValue", typeof(string), typeof(ExampleUserControl));
    public string SomeStringValue
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(SomeStringValueProperty) as string;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SomeStringValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public ExampleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**The Main Window it's hosted in:**

```
<Window x:Class="ExampleApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExampleApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel>
        <local:ExampleUserControl SomeStringValue="Test 1" />
        <local:ExampleUserControl SomeStringValue="Test 2" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

**Here is what the designer looks like:**

[image: Screenshot of error in designer]

**Here is what the XAML designer looks like:**
[image: XAML]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What's happening is the Dependency Property is getting Registered multiple times under the same name and owner. Dependency Properties are intended to have a single owner, and should be statically instanced. If you don't statically instance them, an attempt will be made to register them for each instance of the control.

**Make your DependencyProperty declaration static.
Change it from:**

```
 public DependencyProperty SomeStringValueProperty =
                             DependencyProperty.Register("SomeStringValue", 
                                                         typeof(string), 
                                                         typeof(ExampleUserControl));
```

**To:**

```
public static DependencyProperty SomeStringValueProperty =
                             DependencyProperty.Register("SomeStringValue", 
                                                         typeof(string), 
                                                         typeof(ExampleUserControl));
```

Answer (score 12):

My error message of this type was caused by registering a dependency property with a base class

i.e this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WorkerStateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("WorkerState", typeof(State), typeof(Control),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(State.Stopped, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWorkerStateChanged)));
```

instead of this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty WorkerStateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("WorkerState", typeof(State), typeof(WorkerControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(State.Stopped, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnWorkerStateChanged)));
```

where my WorkerControl class derived from Control

Answer (score 1):

I did a cut and paste between two controls for the dependency property and forgot to change the registered class away from the first control on the second. Hence duplication.

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentBatchProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(
         "CurrentBatch",
         typeof(Batch),
         typeof({--- Must be same as encompassing class --}), // Error if not set properly.
         new PropertyMetadata(null, OnCurrentBatchPropertyChanged));
```

For upon pasting the code, my original control was *then* registering it in two different controls and it got the squiggly line (on the placement page) and the error.